# Make a Django model class whose one of the field value is calculated by other model's fields values and it must be present in my actual Database table

Tags: python, django

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class model_A(models.Model):
  value_1 = models.IntegerField()
  value_2 = models.FloatField()

class model_B(modles.Model):
  value_3 = models.FloatField()
  value_4 = (model_A.value_1 - model_B.value_2)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import model_A, model_B

model_lst = [model_A, model_B]

for i in model_lst:
    admin.site.register(i)
```

I want model_B to have value_4 as separate column in database table(model_B)

Comment: Plz fix your snippet, currently your code makes no sense. You cannot subtract fields on models.

Comment: @jerch kindly check... want value_4 col of database table model_B to be the diff of values from table model_A vakue_1 and vakue_2

Comment: It still does not work that way - you need instances to do that. To get instances, you need to express the relation of `model_A` to `model_B` somehow (e.g. by an fk or o2o field). With that field in place, you can express `value_4` during querytime as annotated field, e.g. `qs_on_B.annotate(value4=F('fk_to_A__value_1') - F('value_3'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use computedfield:

https://pypi.org/project/django-computedfields/

Comment: Plz note that django-computedfields as a denormalization pattern is only useful for certain query bottlenecks of a highly normalized DB scheme, and should only be used if you are aware of desync issues around data duplication. It should never be used to get around proper normalization and perf tests with annotated fields in the first place.